# Call to Google feeds/contacts/ does not return groupMembershipInfo on some accounts

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

On a newly-created Google account, when I make a call to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0&alt=json , in part of the response I receive an array called 'gContact$groupMembershipInfo', which tells me what groups a certain contact is in.

In some older Google accounts I've tested, this array is completely missing, even though there are contacts with actual group memberships in that account's contact list.

Code to get information:

```
try {
    $req = new Google_HttpRequest(
        "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0&alt=json" . ($query == "" ? "" : "&q=$query")
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_message("ERROR", "Error contacting Google servers. Please try again.");
    return;
}
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

$contacts_object = json_decode($val->getResponseBody())->feed->entry;
echo '<pre>' . print_r($contacts_object, true) . '</pre>';
```

Here's the output information. Note the ID string on each contact: the working account uses a hash to identify the contact, while the non-working account uses sequential integer indexes to do so.

The output I want, and which works on my own account:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gd$etag] => "QXs4..."
            [id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/redacted%40gmail.com/base/11...c1
                )

            [updated] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => 2013-10-21T15:43:10.536Z
                )

            [app$edited] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [xmlns$app] => http://www.w3.org/2007/app
                    [$t] => 2013-10-21T15:43:10.536Z
                )

            ...
            [category, title, link, gd$name, gd$email, gd$phoneNumber, gd$structuredPostalAddress]
            ...

            [gContact$groupMembershipInfo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deleted] => false
                            [href] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/redacted%40gmail.com/base/6
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deleted] => false
                            [href] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/redacted%40gmail.com/base/55f1...cdad
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [deleted] => false
                            [href] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/redacted%40gmail.com/base/2d7a...8456
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

The response I get with the problem accounts:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [gd$etag] => "QH4_e...LRwQ."
            [id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/redacted%40gmail.com/base/2
                )

            [updated] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => 2012-07-16T01:10:01.041Z
                )

            [app$edited] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [xmlns$app] => http://www.w3.org/2007/app
                    [$t] => 2012-07-16T01:10:01.041Z
                )

            [category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                            [term] => http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact
                        )

                )

            [title] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => Redacted
                )

            [link] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo
                            [type] => image/*
                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/redacted%40gmail.com/2?v=3.0
                            [gd$etag] => "cT52JngabCt7I2BqPWgHTk1ZNmcaPT8mTCY."
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [rel] => self
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/redacted%40gmail.com/full/2?v=3.0
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [rel] => edit
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/redacted%40gmail.com/full/2?v=3.0
                        )

                )

            [gd$name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [gd$fullName] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [$t] => Redacted
                        )

                    [gd$givenName] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [$t] => Redacted
                        )

                )

            [gd$email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other
                            [address] => redacted@gmail.com
                            [primary] => true
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

As you can see, [gContact$groupMembershipInfo] is missing.

Is it possible the problem account is a legacy issue? Is there any other way to get group info for a particular contact?